# New instance of parent object created when adding children

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, parent-child

I created a function that will copy child attributes to a parent attribute. Let my parent class be `A` with many Children of class `B`. I am adding children to  `A` which are already children of some other parent (Copying of instances of child class to avoid extra overhead of entering values). I created a `CopyProperty` function which will take the Parent ID and list of selected `ChildInstances` as parameters.

**Post method**

```
 public ActionResult CopyProperty(TechnicalCharacteristic model, int[] setid)
 {
    var req_tcset = new List<TcSet>();
    foreach(var item in setid)
        req_tcset.Add(db.TcSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TcSetID == item));
    foreach(var item in req_tcset)
    {
        if (!model.TcSets.Any(x => x.TcSetID == item.TcSetID))
        {
           var add = new TcSet { TechnicalCharacteristic = model, TechnicalCharacteristicID = model.TechnicalCharacteristicID };
           add.SetName = item.SetName;
           add.DescriptionDE = item.SetName;
           db.TcSet.Add(add);
           db.SaveChanges();
        }
   }
```

When I save the child class, the same parent class object is also created with the same values of the passed model. I want the children to be added to the parent class and not a to a new instance of parent class.

**Additional Info from DB**

In the database, ID of the parent is also changed to the new model ID. I really can't understadn why it should happen. The children of the parent class from where the `CopyProperty` is called are deleted ans assigned to the new parent which has all the details excatly as same as the original parent. But at the end I have multiple copies of the parent.

Comment: Not an answer but unless you are sure TcSets is never null , then:
if (!model.TcSets.Any(x => x.TcSetID == item.TcSetID)) should be 
    if (model.TcSets != null && !model.TcSets.Any(x => x.TcSetID == item.TcSetID))

Comment: But it works even when it is null. I just checked after creating a new parent object and tried copying children. it worked

Comment: null.Any will always throw System.ArgumentNullException - it will work if it was an empty collection.

Comment: @Ahmad :  I checked it again. I created a new parent object which has no child objects; called copy function ; and it executed without throwing an exception..  maybe i am missing something from your point

Comment: A null collecicton is different from an empty collection. An empty collection has no children and hence it works with the Any query.But null collection is a collection that has never been initiated ... A general rule is to always ask yourself if an object could be null whenever you write a linq query.

Comment: OK. I understand. But in my case it wouldn't be necessary i guess. Because there are only two cases where parent could have no children :  When a parent is newly created or all the children were deleted. But in both cases my query executes. But I understand your point of checking if the children class is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becouse you are creating the model in your code in this line:

```
new TcSet { TechnicalCharacteristic = model, TechnicalCharacteristicID = model.TechnicalCharacteristicID };
```

You should either use `Attach()` to let EF know that it's existing object or just get actuall model from your db like this:

```
new TcSet { 
   TechnicalCharacteristic = db.TechnicalCharacteristics.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id), 
   TechnicalCharacteristicID = model.TechnicalCharacteristicID 
};
```

If you have Id of parent property it's better to do like this:

```
new TcSet { 
       TechnicalCharacteristicID = model.TechnicalCharacteristicID 
    };
```

Comment: But with that line I just meant to assign the TechnicalCharactersitic Property to the new child. But I will change and try :)

Comment: @Vini EF just think that your property is new entry. If you have id it's ok to set Id only withoud property `TechnicalCharacteristic `

Comment: Yes. It was right. So i understand I do  not have to assign the parent in the child class while creating. I only need to assign the parent id. It worked right now :)